# Trouble selecting data from MSSQL View PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am using PDO to get data from MSSQL but I cant seem to get any results when I select it from a view.

This is what I got.

My view is called `cdr_view`. The view definitely has data if I run the same SQL
And a table is called `cdr`.

```
    <?php
$conn = new \PDO("dblib:host=host;dbname=XC5_XS","someuser","somepass");
$stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from cdr_view;"); //0 results
//$stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from cdr;"); //get heaps of results.
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
          print_r($row);
        }
```

Do i need to use `view.cdr_view` or somehow let the database know that it is a view I want and not a table?

Comment: have u check the rowCount()?, so that you can check the values in while loop

Comment: rowcount was zero. Apparently there might have been an issue with the view. Someone re-created the view and now I get data using the exact same code. It was somewhat strange that I did not get data before.